# How do I output 256 or even 24-bit colours in Git Bash?

Tags: windows-10, command-line, bash, colors

I'm running Git Bash on Windows 10 Creators Update build 15063. During the installation of Git for Windows I chose to *Use Windows' default console window* instead of MinTTY.

The default console window means cmd.exe, also known as the Command Prompt or Command Processor. [Since build 14931 of Windows 10 cmd.exe supports 24-bit colour](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/commandline/2016/09/22/24-bit-color-in-the-windows-console/).

**How can I 'unlock' the new 24-bit colour support in Windows 10 Creators Update for Git Bash?**

Since cmd.exe also supports ANSI escape codes now, I tested 24-bit colour support in cmd.exe (not Git Bash) using the following command:

```
echo ^[[48;2;0;191;243m^[[38;2;255;255;255m Ask Question ^[[0m
```

(The character sequence `^[` are actually the visual representation of the escape control character, which I entered using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>[</kbd>.)

[image: 24-bit color support in cmd.exe]

I tested 24-bit colour support as well as 'normal' 8-colour support in Git Bash using the commands below. Git Bash only outputs colours when using the basic (non-extended) ANSI escape codes.

```
echo -e "\033[48;2;0;191;243m\033[38;2;255;255;255m Ask Question \033[0m"

echo -e "\033[44m\033[37m Ask Question \033[0m"
```

[image: Git Bash]

Changing the value of the `TERM` environment variable from `cygwin` to `xterm-256color` did not fix it.

Comment: "Changing the value of the TERM environment variable from cygwin to xterm-256color did not fix it." That is to be expected. A windows console window is not an xterm window.

Comment: `echo -e "\033[48;2;0;191;243m\033[38;2;255;255;255m Ask Question \033[0m"` works for me in (Cygwin) mintty.

Comment: `cmd.exe` is not a very good terminal application (though it has been getting better as you noted). I highly suggest [mintty](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mintty) (which is the default "Cygwin Terminal") as noted in this [mildly related answer](https://superuser.com/a/1253812/300293 "How do I change font colours on Babun in Windows / Cgywin").

Answer (score 1):

Upgrading Git Bash should allow it to work. If you run:

```
echo -e "\033[48;2;0;191;243m\033[38;2;255;255;255m Ask Question \033[0m"
```

It will return the corresponding color. Here is what the output text will look like:

[image: Example showing the colored version of the text output.]

To update Git Bash, just [download](https://gitforwindows.org/) it from the link. The installer should be able to detect that you already have Git Bash installed and it just needs to update.